# Is there a way to share info between two wso2 messages in a clone mediator (WSO2 4.8.1)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

For example y a clone mediator

```
<clone id="cloneId1" sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <sequence key="Clone1Sequence"></sequence>
           </sequence>
        </target>
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <sequence key="Clone2Sequence"></sequence>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </clone>
```

I only must execute Clone2Sequence depending of the Clone1Sequence result and Clone2Sequence need the information in the original message.
I think the solution is share properties between the two messages in the clone but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So if you executing this sequentially, you can use call mediator without clone? If you need orignal message body you can save it from enrich mediator toa property and use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Save the original message using enrich mediator:

   `<enrich>
     <source clone="true" type="body"/>
      target property="REQUEST_Original" type="property"/>
    </enrich>`
2. Call Clone1Sequence and take the required response value.

   `<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
       <format>
         <req>
           ........
         </req>
       </format>
       <args>
         .....
       </args>
     </payloadFactory>
     <sequence key="Clone1Sequence"/>`
3. Validate with that response value if you need to call or not the Clone2Sequence.

   `<property description="responsevalue"
       expression="//p:response/p:value"
       name="responsevalue" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
     <enrich>
       <source clone="true" property="REQUEST_Original" type="property"/>
       <target type="body"/>
     </enrich>
     <sequence key="Clone2Sequence"/>`

Comment: Thank you very much. your alternative help us to solve our problem